Deprecation Warning: The legacy JS API is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0
Hello everyone Why does the error "Deprecation Warning: The legacy JS API is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0." occur? I have searched for an answer in other help requests, but I have not found an answer. Answers by type:
css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          api: "modern-compiler", // or "modern", "legacy"
          importers: [],
        },
    },
},

They don't help!
Here is my Vite config:
// default.config.ts
export const defaultConfig: InlineConfig = {
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                api: "modern-compiler",
                importers: [],
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        tsPaths(),
        solidPlugin(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@styles": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/styles"),
        },
    },
};

// dev.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        port: 3000,
        strictPort: true,
        open: true,
        hmr: true,
    },
    ...defaultConfig,
});

My package file:
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite --host",
        "build": "VITE_APP_ENV=production vite build",
        "serve": "vite preview"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^6.0.0",
        "@types/node": "^22.5.5",
        "@types/pako": "^2.0.3",
        "@types/postcss-normalize": "^9.0.4",
        "cssnano": "^7.0.6",
        "lightningcss": "^1.27.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.47",
        "postcss-combine-duplicated-selectors": "^10.0.3",
        "sass": "^1.78.0",
        "solid-devtools": "^0.29.2",
        "svgo": "^3.3.2",
        "terser": "^5.32.0",
        "typescript": "^5.3.3",
        "vconsole": "^3.15.1",
        "vite": "^5.0.11",
        "vite-bundle-visualizer": "^1.2.1",
        "vite-plugin-html-minifier-terser": "^3.8.0",
        "vite-plugin-solid": "^2.8.2",
        "vite-plugin-solid-svg": "^0.8.1",
        "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^5.0.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@solidjs/router": "^0.14.5",
        "lottie-web": "^5.12.2",
        "pako": "^2.1.0",
        "solid-js": "^1.8.11"
    }
}

I tried adding and removing scss and sass settings - it didn't help. I deleted plugins, changed the config, deleted packages - it didn't help. Where is the error - I do not understand
UPDATE: Why is the question different from the others? The problem relates to the Vite version. The solution to other problems from other authors has been found, but my case is related to vite, more precisely with version 5.4.x (I suspect that this is 5.4.6, since everything works in 5.4.5)
UPDATE2:I just checked other versions of vite below 5.4.0 and the problem persists. At the same time, just a day ago, everything was fine

Can you check your config? Something tells me that it gets overwritten at some point. The following code should solve the issue as it forces you to use "modern" instead of "legacy." Legacy sends the warnings but not the modern/modern-compiler options.
Docs: https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#css-preprocessoroptions
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        api: 'modern-compiler',
      }
    }
  }

